# CPANM Couldn't find module or a distribution String::CRC32

Tags: perl, cpanm

I am trying to install String::CRC32 lib within Strawberry portable Perl version.
It works on my local PC using:
portableshall.bat

> cpanm String::CRC32

However I am not able to install it on the server.
I become WARNING when executing portableshall.bat:
UNC-Path not supported. Windows Path will be used as path: C:\Windows.

> Finding String::CRC32 on cpanmetadb failed.
> cannot open file 'H:/.cpanm/sources/http%www.cpan.org/02packages.details.txt.gz': No such file or directory opening compressed index
> Couldn't find module or a distribution String::CRC32

Any ideas?